# Fill pd.Series from list of values if value exist in another df.Series description

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I need to solve tricky problem, and minimize big O notation problem.

I have two pandas dataframes:

The first df is like as:

```
| source | searchTermsList |

|:---- |:------:|

| A  | [t1, t2, t3,...tn] |
| B  | [t4, t5, t6,...tn] |
| C  | [t7, t8, t9,...tn] |
```

Where the first column is string, the second one is a list of strings no duplicated, just unique values.

The second dataframe, which I need to create a new pd.Series with first column (df1.source) if term in searchTerm list, exist in the follow df2.Series, called "description".

```
Example.
| objID | dataDescr |

|:---- |:------:|

| 1  | The first description name has t2 | 
| 2  | The second description name has t6 and t7| 
| 3  | The third description name has t8, t1, t9|
```

**Expected results**

```
| objID | dataDescr | source |

|:---- |:------:| -----:|

| 1  | The first description name    | A |
| 2  | The second description name    | B |
| 3  | The third description name    | C |
```

**Explanation**

- The first description has t2, so the column filled with A, because t2 appears in the term list.
- The second description has two terms, t6 and t7, in that case match only the first one with the second list, so the source will be filled B
- The third description has three terms, as above, only get the first one with the list and source will be filled with C.

**My approach**

If I split descrName and finally search that word in the all lists, maybe the computational cost will be very huge. The idea with map, doesn't work, because with haven't ordered dataframe, in the first just we have 10-20 rows, only unique values, in the second will be to matching with each terms n times.

Any suggestion,please?

Comment: What is size of `df1, df2`? What is size of lists?

Comment: df1 has min. 8 rows. (max 20). Each list has n words, no duplicates inside, are search terms stored so, each word could be appear in another list of terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create`Series` by [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for indices of `searchTermsList` for mapping first:

```
s = df1.explode('searchTermsList').set_index('searchTermsList')['source']
print (s)
t1    A
t2    A
t3    A
t4    B
t5    B
t6    B
t7    C
t8    C
t9    C
Name: source, dtype: object
```

Then join values of `s.index` by `|` for regex `or`, `\b\b` are words boundaries. For get first matched value is used [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and then mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
pat = r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(s.index))

df2['searchTermsList'] = df2['dataDescr'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).map(s)
print (df2)
   objID                                  dataDescr searchTermsList
0      1          The first description name has t2               A
1      2  The second description name has t6 and t7               B
2      3  The third description name has t8, t1, t9               C
```

Another solution is extract words by `re.findall` and mapoping by [`Series.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html):

```
import re
s = df1.explode('searchTermsList').set_index('searchTermsList')['source']

f = lambda x: next((s.get(y) for y in re.findall(r'\b\w+\b',x) if y in s), np.nan)
df2['searchTermsList'] = df2['dataDescr'].apply(f)
print (df2)
   objID                                  dataDescr searchTermsList
0      0                    The first description n             NaN
1      1          The first description name has t2               A
2      2  The second description name has t6 and t7               B
3      3  The third description name has t8, t1, t9               C
```